# Validate Username and Password in a domain or machine

Tags: c#, windows, security, authentication, dns

What I want to do is when the user type in the following:
Domain\UserName
Password

I can the validate if the user and password is valid or not, Domain can be LDAP/AD or machine, all the sample code I can find are validating against AD, which is not too suitable in my scenario, any help would be appreciate.

Many thank

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How to validate domain credentials?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326818/c-how-to-validate-domain-credentials)

Answer (score 0):

This explains how you could do it in .Net3.5

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx#S9