# Unable to authenticate with LdapConnection C# on IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory, ldapconnection

I am trying to authenticate using active directory and C#. The code is working on IIS Express under Visual Studio 15 but when I deploy my project to an IIS server, the LDAP connection returns the following error :

> "The Supplied Credential is invalid"

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static dynamic AuthenticationUser(string username, string password)
{
    bool validation;
    try
    {
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, "somedomain");
        var serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("someserver");
        LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));

        conn.Credential = credentials;
        conn.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
        conn.Bind(credentials);
        validation = true;
    }
    catch (LdapException ex)
    {
        validation = false;
        return ex.Message;
    }
```

Everything is OK when I debug with Visual Studio, I can verify and validate that the user exists on the AD server, but with IIS server the error occurs.

### Update

I fixed this issue by disabling the domain controller on the IIS server.

Comment: Is the server joined to a different domain than your development machine?

Comment: no .. they are in the same domain

Comment: Try setting `AuthType` to `AuthType.Ntlm`. If that works, then it points to a Kerberos problem.

Comment: tried that but not luck :\

Comment: You should check this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111618/win32-how-to-validate-credentials-against-active-directory) about credential validation, and use the `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` method. It is more effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by disabling the domain controller on the IIS server.