# How to check if current PC user is current logged on user?

Tags: c#, windows

For security reasons we want to check if the current PC user is the actual logged on user. To do this we want the user to re-enter their password and check his credentials with the domain. How could we accomplish this?

Sofar we tried this:

```
public static Boolean Authenticate(String password)
{
    String user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; 

    using (PrincipalContext PrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName))
    {
        return PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(user, password);
    }
}
```

But get a `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException`, leaving the `Environment.UserDomainName` off also triggers this exception.

We also tried:

```
public static Boolean Authenticate(String password)
{
    String user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; 

    using (PrincipalContext PrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
    {
        return PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(user, password);
    }
}
```

But this returns true on any password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348236/5272987). Turns out the Domain name is included in `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`. As found under the remarks in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name(v=vs.110).aspx).

Giving this as a working solution:

```
public static Boolean Authenticate(String password)
{
    String user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; //Should be: DomainName\UserName
    String[] DomainAndUserName = user.Split(new Char[] { '\\' }, 2);

    if (DomainAndUserName.Length != 2) { return false; } // No DomainName ==> Wrong network;

    using (PrincipalContext PrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainAndUserName[0]))
    {
            return PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(DomainAndUserName[1], password);
    }
}
```