# How to Validate Credentials from Active Directory when Active Directory server is down

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-4.5

I'm able to validate user credentials when Active directory server is reachable with below code:

```
    using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

However when AD server is down isValid is false.
But I can login to computer, which is most probably because Cached domain logon information provided by MS.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172931

So my question is how can I check also cached passwords?
Because I want user to be able to enter my app when he's able to login to his computer.

Comment: You can try with NTLM, it uses cached credentials. See here for some explanation and effort on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350155/how-to-validate-users-cached-credentials-against-a-domain

Comment: @Martin that SO question also dosn't havea solution? How can I make NTLM with managed code?