# How to get the authority when using SSPI?

Tags: winapi, kerberos, sspi

When you use the Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) API to validate a user's credentials, the server ends up with a [*security context*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secgloss/s-gly) handle.

You can then use the **[`QueryContextAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/querycontextattributes--general)** function to query for information about the security context handle:

- `QueryContextAttributes(handle,` [`SECPKG_ATTR_LIFESPAN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/ns-sspi-secpkgcontext_lifespan)`)`

  - **tsStart**: Time at which the context was established.
  - **tsExpiry**: Time at which the context will expire.
- `QueryContextAttributes(handle,` [`SECPKG_ATTR_AUTHORITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/sspi/ns-sspi-secpkgcontext_authoritya)`)`

  - **sAuthorityName**: the name of the authenticating authority, if available.
- `QueryContextAttributes(handle,` [`SECPKG_ATTR_PASSWORD_EXPIRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/sspi/ns-sspi-secpkgcontext_passwordexpiry)`)`

  - **tsPasswordExpires**: when the credentials for the security context expire.
- `QueryContextAttributes(handle,` [`SECPKG_ATTR_PACKAGE_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/sspi/ns-sspi-_secpkgcontext_packageinfoa)`)`

  - **Name**:  the name of the security package.
  - **Comment**: This can be any additional string passed back by the package.
- `QueryContextAttributes(handle,` [`SECPKG_ATTR_NATIVE_NAMES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/sspi/ns-sspi-_secpkgcontext_nativenamesa)`)`

  - **sClientName**:  the principal name for the client in the outbound ticket.
  - **sServerName**:  the principal name for the server in the outbound ticket
- `QueryContextAttributes(handle,` [`SECPKG_ATTR_CLIENT_SPECIFIED_TARGET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/sspi/ns-sspi-secpkgcontext_clientspecifiedtarget)`)`

  - **sTargetName**: The SPN of the initial target.

When i use SSPI to validate my credentials, the server gets a set of information about **me**, one of the items fails:

- **Context Handle:** `0x04CC9F4000AC8B80`
- **Username:** `STACKOVERFLOW\ian`
- **Native Client Name**: `ian@STACKOVERFLOW.COM`
- **Native Server Name**: `ian@STACKOVERFLOW.COM`
- **User SID:** `S-1-5-21-1708537768-844245398-2146844275-1109`
- **Client Specified Target:** `ian`
- ***Authority:*** ***`The function requested is not supported (80090302)`***
- **Password Expires (UTC):**
- **Lifespan Start:** `10/23/2019 11:03 ᴀᴍ`
- **Lifespan Expiry:** `10/23/2019 7:32 ᴘᴍ`
- **Package Name:** `Kerberos`
- **Package Comment:** `Microsoft Kerberos V1.0`
- **Package Capabilities:** `0x028F3BBF`
- **Package Version:** `0001`
- **Package Rpc ID:** `0010`
- **Package Max Token Length:** `48000`

## Credential authority

I want to know the **authority** who validated (or vouched for the cached) credentials.

Except calling **QueryContextAttributes** (and **QueryContextAttributesEx**) with `SECPKG_ATTR_AUTHORITY` fails with the error:

```
// MessageId: SEC_E_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION
//
// MessageText:
//
//  The function requested is not supported
//

SEC_E_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION       = HRESULT($80090302);
```

What's doing?

I can find it using the command line:

```
C:\Users\Ian>SET

LOGONSERVER=\\HYDROGEN
```

But i'm using APIs.

## Background: How SSPI works

SSPI was designed as a generic wrapper around different security algorithms. The way to use the API is pretty simple:

- **Client**:

  - calls `InitializeSecurityContext` and is given a blob
  - client sends that blob to the server
- **Server**:

  - calls `AcceptSecurityContext(blob)`, and is given a blob back
  - server sends that blob back to the client
- **Client**:

  - calls `InitializeSecurityContext(blob)`, and is given back a blob
  - client sends that blob back to the server
- **Server**:

  - calls `AcceptSecurityContext(blob)`, and is given a blob back
  - *...keep repeating until told to stop...*

Both sides keep going back and forth, until the function stops returning a blob that needs to be sent to the other side:

[image]

And so the with SSPI you do this ping-ponging back and forth until you're told to stop. And so they were able to shoe-horn every authentication scheme into that ping-pong-until-told-to-stop high level abstraction.

### And how do you transmit the blobs?

You transmit the blobs over whatever communication channel you're using.

If you're talking to a remote server over TCP/IP, then you'd probably use that:

```
// Open connection to server
sockConnect(162.210.196.166, 1433);

blob = null;

Boolean bContinue = InitializeSecurityContext(ref blob);

while (bContinue)
{
   sockWrite(blob); //send the blob to the server

   blob = sockRead(); //wait for the server to return a blob 

   bContinue = InitializeSecurityContext(ref blob);
}
```

If you're doing it over http:

```
blob = null;
Boolean bContinue = InitializeSecurityContext(ref blob);

while (bContinue)
{
    http = new HttpRequest("http://4chan.org/default.aspx");
    http.AddHeader("X-SSPI-Blob", blob.ToBase64());
    http.Send();

    blob = http.ReasponseHeader["X-SSPI-Blob"];
    if (blob.IsEmpty())
       break;

    bContinue = InitializeSecurityContext(ref blob);
}
```

You can even send them over carrier pigeon!

### Bonus Reading

SSPI is the name of the Windows implementation of [RFC4121](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4121)

> Generic Security Service Application Program Interface (GSS-API)

### Bonus Bonus

- *"What am i supposed to set **TargetName** to?*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49411527/12597

Comment: [`QueryContextAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-querycontextattributesa) does not support `SECPKG_ATTR_AUTHORITY` attribute, result in parameter invalid error for me. And [`QueryContextAttributesEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-querycontextattributesexa) result in link error for me. It seems it is missed in `Secur32.lib`. So could you show a reproducible demo and steps? I test on Windows 10 1903.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT The link failure would make sense if you're using C/C++; the SDK .lib files are incorrect. Be sure you loading SspiCli.dll, and the exported QueryContextAttributesExW (or Ansi equivalent) function. But i wouldn't work too hard: `QueryContextAttributesEx` also fails.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to find the way. Yes, I reproduced this issue.(error 0x80090302) I'll consult the related engineer for this issue and update here ASAP.

Comment: BTW, what's your Windows version?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT `>ver`: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418]`

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT So, how's that consultation with the related engineer going? Did they have any ideas in the last 3 months?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. They are working on this and will update to you at first time if there is any result.