# Active Directory - Check username / password

Tags: c#, windows-vista, active-directory, ldap

I'm using the following code on Windows Vista Ultimate SP1 to query our active directory server to check the user name and password of a user on a domain.

```
public Object IsAuthenticated()
{
    String domainAndUsername = strDomain + "\\" + strUser;
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, strPass);
    SearchResult result;
    try
    {
        //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.         

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry) { Filter = ("(SAMAccountName=" + strUser + ")") };

        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName"); // First Name                
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn"); // Last Name
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn"); // Last Name

        result = search.FindOne();

        if (null == result)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
        _path = result.Path;
        _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
    }
    return user;
}
```

the target is using .NET 3.5, and compiled with VS 2008 standard

I'm logged in under a domain account that is a domain admin where the application is running.

The code works perfectly on windows XP; but i get the following exception when running it on Vista:

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E): Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
   at Chain_Of_Custody.Classes.Authentication.LdapAuthentication.IsAuthenticated()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
   at Chain_Of_Custody.Classes.Authentication.LdapAuthentication.IsAuthenticated()
```

I've tried changing the authentication types, I'm not sure what's going on.

---

**See also**: [[Validate a username and password against Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory)

Comment: Is this really an exact duplicate? This person is getting an exception message, not asking how to do it...

Comment: Since you're using .NET 3.5, you might choose to use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. I'm not using Vista at work, but since this is geared for 3.5, it might be more compatible with Vista...

Comment: I wouldn't call this a dupe....

Comment: I figured it out anyhow

If you pass in the domain with the username on vista it does not work
like "domain\user" so just passing "user" instead seems to work okay - except you have to be on the same domain

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you're using .net 3.5 use this code instead.

To authenticate a user:

```
PrincipalContext adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

using (adContext)
{
     return adContext.ValidateCredentials(UserName, Password);
}
```

If you need to find the user to R/W attributes to the object do this:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal foundUser = 
    UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "jdoe");
```

This is using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace so you'll need to add it to your using statements.

If you need to convert a UserPrincipal object to a DirectoryEntry object to work with legacy code you can do this:

```
DirectoryEntry userDE = (DirectoryEntry)foundUser.GetUnderlyingObject();
```

Comment: Hi @steve, you mean we do not need to give the domain name while defining principal context? Then How will it know against which domain it should verify?

Also, can you please point me to its documentation, i am unable to find it.

Answer (score 8):

I found that same code floating around the Internet on multiple websites and it didn't work for me. Steve Evans is probably right that if you're on .NET 3.5, you should not use this code. But if you ARE still on .NET 2.0 you can try this to Authenticate to your AD services:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, 
   userName, password, 
   AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);
object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
```

The first line creates a DirectoryEntry object using domain, username, and password. It also sets the AuthenticationTypes. Notice how I'm setting both Secure (Kerberos) Authentication and SSL using the "Bitwise OR" ( '|' ) operator between the two parameters.

The second line forces the NativeObject of "entry" to Bind to the AD services using the information from the first line.

If an exception is thrown, then the credentials (or settings) were bad. If no exception, you're authenticated. The exception message will usually indicate what went wrong.

This code is pretty similar to what you already have, but the domain is used where you have "path", and the username is not combined with the domain. Be sure to set your AuthenticationTypes properly, too. This can make or break the ability to authenticate.

Comment: The question relates to .Net 3.5; not .Net 2.0.

Comment: This is the first answer I've seen that combines the Secure and SecureSocketsLayer flags, which is the only way I've managed to make it work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out anyhow If you pass in the domain with the username on vista it does not work like "domain\user" so just passing "user" instead seems to work okay - except you have to be on the same domain

Comment: you should be able to change domain, by going user@domain as well

Answer (score 0):

Does binding to LDAP require elevated privs (UAC)?  You could try running Visual Studio and/or the app as Administrator and see if that helps.  If that's the problem you could always add a manifest to the application and set it to require elevation, that way it will prompt when a user runs it.

Not sure why it would require elevated privs, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Running as an administrator does not help