# Error changing password of user using WinNT string connection (and authenticating the current password)

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, invoke

I am developing a website which will authenticate the user and change the old password with new password.

I am using WinNT string connection and setting password, without the old password check, works.

My code is as below:

```
'actual setting password
            Dim entryD As New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer")

            Dim NewUser As DirectoryEntry = entryD.Children.Find(username, "user")


            Dim nativeobject As Object = NewUser.NativeObject
            NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", New Object() {strPassNew})

            NewUser.CommitChanges()
            'setting password ends
```

This works fine, but authentication code is not working.

It is as below:

```
'authentication starts
            Dim adsiPath As String

            adsiPath = String.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1},user", domain, username)

            Dim userEntry = New DirectoryEntry(adsiPath, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)

            'Dim nativeobject1 As Object = userEntry.NativeObject

            Dim newobj As ActiveDs.IADsUser = userEntry.NativeObject


            authent = True

            'authentication ends
```

This authenticates but the exception which it throws is:

```
logon failure: unknown username or bad password
```

for the first time, but if i do it again the error is:

> "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.
>   "

Which I don't want to happen... I don't want to use LDAP, I want a solution please, to authenticate the old password.  Please help?

Comment: what line is the exception? I dont see where your actually authenticating? see these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400872/active-directory-check-username-password and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-sharp-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory

Comment: Dim newobj As ActiveDs.IADsUser = userEntry.NativeObject
i get the exception on this line.

Comment: Dim userEntry = New DirectoryEntry(adsiPath, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
this is the line i m using to authenticate,

Comment: is there anything in the event logs? are you following any sample code/article? are all the codes permissions ok - like perhaps the error message is misleading and means its not the users credentials its the applications?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in my code where requirement was to add domain users to local admin group of a system. While testing the code after the first try I used to get "Multiple connections to a server ..." error and then I if try the code code later(an hour or so) it worked fine. After searching thru various forms I came know the we can see user logged-on to a computer using

```
NET SESSION /LIST
```

command in cmd of remote system and it appears that when we use WinNT provider it actually creates an user session with idle  timeout on remote computer (there can be a situation where other programs are creating sessions) which conflicts the connection when you try for second time. So I tried deleting the previous session by

```
NET SESSION \\RequestingComputerName /DELETE
```

then I did n't got the error. If that doesn't solve the problem then the last resort is to restart the system.