# How to check the valid user's password matches with active directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm passing username and password to check whether a user is valid from Active Directory.

Here is my code :

```
  private bool ValidUser(string name, string userPwd)
    {

        string UserName = "XXXXXXXXXX";
        string Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        DirectoryEntry objRootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("XXXXXXXX.com", UserName, Password);
        DirectorySearcher objADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(objRootEntry);
        objADSearcher.Filter = ("(&(sAMAccountType=xxxxxxxxx)(samAccountName=" + name + "))");
        SearchResult objResult = objADSearcher.FindOne();
        DirectoryEntry objLoginEntry = (objResult != null) ? objResult.GetDirectoryEntry() : null;          
        if (objLoginEntry != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now it checks the user name alone.I need to check whether the entering password (userPwd) matches with the Active directory. How to do that.

Please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Active Directory - Check username / password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400872/active-directory-check-username-password)

Comment: What versions of .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//You are entering password while finding in Directory entry is enough. Don't need to check again

Check this detail code

```
public bool ValidateUser(string domain, string username, string password,string LdapPath, out string Errmsg)
        {
            Errmsg = "";
            string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LdapPath, domainAndUsername, password);
            try
            {
                // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
                Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                if (null == result)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                // Update the new path to the user in the directory
                LdapPath = result.Path;
                string _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Errmsg = ex.Message;                   
                throw new Exception("Error authenticating user." + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: FYI - `throw new Exception("Error authenticating user." + ex.Message);` will never execute.

Comment: I got it! changes made

Comment: are you checking entered password (userPwd) with the active directory object's(objLoginEntry) password ?

Comment: The password got checked if you got a valid `entry.NativeObject` for the `entry` you created with the user/pwd you would like to check