# Check active directory passwords with ironpython

Tags: active-directory, ironpython

I'm an admin on an active domain and most of my users use the same password,
I find all those users so that I could ask them to change their password.

I was thinking that iron python would be good tool to get this done.

How would I get this accomplished?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply not possible directly: AD passwords are stored as hashes (not cleartext) and that hash [is not readable](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/63e3cf2d-f186-418e-bc85-58bdc1861aae).

If you know what that shared password is, you could use the answers from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory/499716#499716) and check against every user account, but I wouldn't. For one, it'll count against their bad password limit, and two, it seems kind of dirty.

If employees are sharing passwords, I would make it clear (preferably coming from HR, as no one listens to IT anyway) that the employee is resposible for anything done under their user account.