# Verify domain credentials at command line

Tags: windows, command-line, authentication, dns, credentials

Is there a windows command that will allow me to verify a domain account/password?

Comment: Related [C# Validate a username and password against Active Directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory)

Comment: is there a way to do this using built in commands? or is it necessary to create a program to do so?

Comment: you might want to include a tag for windows, so people that monitor for new questions  by tag will see your question.

Comment: Authentication may fail for a lot of reasons like ERROR_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT, ERROR_INVALID_LOGON_HOURS or ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE. It may not validate your credentials at all before returning an error.

Answer (score 21):

You could use the command [RUNAS](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html), it is not technically a commandline to validate credentials, but it CAN be used for that.

```
runas /noprofile /user:mycomputer\administrator "notepad"
```

If it fails it returns:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - notepad
1326: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Comment: When you press enter, it'll prompt you for the user's password. Just mentioning here because it confused me :)

Answer (score 4):

RUNAS works great on a local system.

To verify credentials on a remote computer, I use the PSExec tool from SysInternals.  I specify the username, then it prompts me for the password.  Here is an example of what my command looks like:

```
psexec \\RemoteComputer -u DOMAIN\USER cmd.exe
```

If I enter the correct password, I'll be greeted with a command prompt.  If I enter the wrong password, I get this:

```
PsExec could not start cmd.exe on RemoteComputer:
The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this powershell script which does some extra testing (domain reachable, user name exists, account enabled, account unlocked).
Got this script from [this post](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Test-Domain-b71cc520). Put this in a notepad, save as .ps1 and execute. It will prompt for credentials and provide feedback. Worked perfectly for my needs.

```
<#  
        .SYNOPSIS  
            Test domain username/password combination are correct 
        .DESCRIPTION  
            This script will check if the password for a given username is correct. If the authentication failed using the provided Domain\Username and Password. 
            The script will do some checks and provide some clues why the authentication failed. 
            The checks are: 
                * Domain is reachable. 
                * User Name exists in the domain. 
                * The account is Enabled. 
                * The account is Unlocked. 
        .EXAMPLE  
            .\Test-UserCredentials.ps1 
            or 
            Right click the script and select "Run with PowerShell" 
        .Notes 
            Created by: Ibrahim Soliman 
            Version: 1.6 (Enhanced error handling, and authentication failure root cause analysis.) 
 #>  

 #Import Active Directory Module 
 Import-Module Activedirectory 

 #Clear User Info Function 
    Function ClearUserInfo 
    { 
        $Cred = $Null 
        $DomainNetBIOS = $Null 
        $UserName  = $Null 
        $Password = $Null 
    } 

#Rerun The Script Function 
 Function Rerun 
    { 
        $Title = "Test Another Credentials?" 
        $Message = "Do you want to Test Another Credentials?" 
        $Yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Test Another Credentials." 
        $No = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "End Script." 
        $Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($Yes, $No) 
        $Result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($Title, $Message, $Options, 0)  

        Switch ($Result) 
        { 
            0 {TestUserCredentials} 
            1 {"End Script."} 
        } 
    } 

#Test User Credentials Function 
Function TestUserCredentials 
{ 
    ClearUserInfo    
    #Get user credentials 
    $Cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Your Credentials (Domain\Username)" 
    if ($Cred -eq $Null) 
                        { 
                            Write-Host "Please enter your username in the form of Domain\UserName and try again" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow 
                            Rerun 
                            Break                           
                        } 

    #Parse provided user credentials 
    $DomainNetBIOS = $Cred.username.Split("{\}")[0] 
    $UserName = $Cred.username.Split("{\}")[1] 
    $Password = $Cred.GetNetworkCredential().password 

    Write-Host "`n" 
    Write-Host "Checking Credentials for $DomainNetBIOS\$UserName" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor White 
    Write-Host "***************************************" 

    If ($DomainNetBIOS -eq $Null -or $UserName -eq $Null)  
                        { 
                            Write-Host "Please enter your username in the form of Domain\UserName and try again" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow 
                            Rerun 
                            Break 
                        } 
    #    Checks if the domain in question is reachable, and get the domain FQDN. 
    Try 
    { 
        $DomainFQDN = (Get-ADDomain $DomainNetBIOS).DNSRoot 
    } 
    Catch 
    { 
        Write-Host "Error: Domain was not found: " $_.Exception.Message -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 
        Write-Host "Please make sure the domain NetBios name is correct, and is reachable from this computer" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 
        Rerun 
        Break 
    } 

    #Checks user credentials against the domain 
    $DomainObj = "LDAP://" + $DomainFQDN 
    $DomainBind = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($DomainObj,$UserName,$Password) 
    $DomainName = $DomainBind.distinguishedName 

    If ($DomainName -eq $Null) 
        { 
            Write-Host "Domain $DomainFQDN was found: True" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 

            $UserExist = Get-ADUser -Server $DomainFQDN -Properties LockedOut -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $UserName} 
            If ($UserExist -eq $Null)  
                        { 
                            Write-Host "Error: Username $Username does not exist in $DomainFQDN Domain." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 
                            Rerun 
                            Break 
                        } 
            Else  
                        {    
                            Write-Host "User exists in the domain: True" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 


                            If ($UserExist.Enabled -eq "True") 
                                    { 
                                        Write-Host "User Enabled: "$UserExist.Enabled -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 
                                    } 

                            Else 
                                    { 
                                        Write-Host "User Enabled: "$UserExist.Enabled -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor RED 
                                        Write-Host "Enable the user account in Active Directory, Then check again" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor RED 
                                        Rerun 
                                        Break 
                                    } 

                            If ($UserExist.LockedOut -eq "True") 
                                    { 
                                        Write-Host "User Locked: " $UserExist.LockedOut -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 
                                        Write-Host "Unlock the User Account in Active Directory, Then check again..." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor RED 
                                        Rerun 
                                        Break 
                                    } 
                            Else 
                                    { 
                                        Write-Host "User Locked: " $UserExist.LockedOut -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 
                                    } 
                        } 

            Write-Host "Authentication failed for $DomainNetBIOS\$UserName with the provided password." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 
            Write-Host "Please confirm the password, and try again..." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 
            Rerun 
            Break 
        } 

    Else 
        { 
        Write-Host "SUCCESS: The account $Username successfully authenticated against the domain: $DomainFQDN" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 
        Rerun 
        Break 
        } 
}     

TestUserCredentials 
ClearUserInfo
```

Comment: This method will work for service accounts that lack the user right that allows them to login.