# How do I connect to a local host using PrincipalContext?

Tags: c#, .net

I know this has a simple solution, but I can't seem to make it work...

Using other [Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory) and [Microsoft's Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299773.aspx), I know that `PrincipalContext` must be set up like this:

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");
```

or also like this:

```
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"YOURDOMAIN", null,ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer);
```

My question is, what do I put for the `"YOURDOMAIN"` attribute if I am connecting to a local host?

Trying this ended in a `PrincipalServerDownException`:

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "localhost:3600")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? :

```
   PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce but that also resulted in a `PrincipalServerDownException` .. In Microsoft's docs I saw that they used something like `"foo.com"` for the `"YOURDOMAIN"` parameter .. so that's why I tried `"localhost:3600"` but it keeps bombing

Comment: @AngeloS: Are you sure you specified `ContextType.Machine`? `PrincipalServerDownException` is pretty bizarre when connecting to the local SAM store.