# Is it possible to authenticate an Active Directory User with an Expired password?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I have a web form that uses AD to authenticate users. I want to be able to authenticate users with expired password, and redirect them to the password change page after authentication.

if for instance, a site admin reset a users password, I use the method below, to make the user reset their password on next logon.

```
Public Shared Sub ForceUserToResetPassword(ByVal LDAP_URI As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal       Auth_UserName As String, ByVal Auth_Password As String)
    Dim LDAPEntry As DirectoryEntry = Nothing
    Try
        LDAPEntry = New DirectoryEntry(LDAP_URI, Auth_UserName, Auth_Password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
        Dim LDAPSearch As New DirectorySearcher()
        LDAPSearch.SearchRoot = LDAPEntry
        LDAPSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & UserName & "))"


        LDAPSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
        Dim results As SearchResult = LDAPSearch.FindOne()
        If Not (results Is Nothing) Then
            LDAPEntry = New DirectoryEntry(results.Path, Auth_UserName, Auth_Password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
        End If

        LDAPAccess.SetProperty(LDAPEntry, "pwdLastSet", 0)
        LDAPEntry.CommitChanges()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Doing this makes the user's password expire. If the user try to logon with their new password the authentication fails with "Logon failure: unknown username or bad password".

This is my auth. method:

```
Public Shared Function AuthADuser(ByVal LDAP_URI As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal Auth_UserName As String, ByVal Auth_Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim IsAuth As Boolean = False
    Dim LDAPEntry As DirectoryEntry = Nothing
    Try
        LDAPEntry = New DirectoryEntry(LDAP_URI, UserName, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
        Dim tmp As [Object] = LDAPEntry.NativeObject
        IsAuth = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        LDAPEntry.Dispose()
        If ex.Message.StartsWith("The server is not operational") Then
            IsAuth = False
        ElseIf ex.Message.StartsWith("Logon failure:") Then
            Throw New ApplicationException("The Username and password combination are not valid to enter the system.")
        End If
    Finally
        LDAPEntry.Close()
    End Try
    Return IsAuth
End Function
```

Is there a way around this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems like a wasted effort. If their password is expired and needs to be changed, then logging in to the domain will prompt for a password change long before they open their web browser and access your intranet site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, if a user is required to Change his Password at Next Logon (User's password has expired) Active-Directory will not allow us to use LDAP to determine if his password is invalid or not. This is due to the fact that a user must change password. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory) the following solution :

To determine if password is expired, you may call Win32:LogonUser(), and check the windows error code for the following 2 constants:

```
ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE = 1907
ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 1330
```

**I have a non official answer**. As administrator you put `pwdLastSet` to -1 for the user where `pwdLastSet` is set to 0. The effect of this is to make Active-Directory believe that the password has just been changed. Then, you check the password with your `AuthADuser` method. Then you put back `pwdLastSet` to 0. I do not test it, but just imagine it, it's not so clean on the security point of view (in France we call that "*bricolage*").

Just tell me if it works ?

I hope it helps;

JP