# Can i do Authentication with Active Directory in C# with MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I want to know if it possible do an application with authentication with active directory in MVC 3 with c#? Thank you

Comment: You can also use Fluent Security Nuget (http://www.fluentsecurity.net/)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is (drumroll please)... **Yes!** :)

Jokes aside, you can try the [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx), but I've found in practice it was simpler to authenticate manually since we have a complex environment, so YMMV.  Here's a good place to start if you have to go that route: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Here's a similar question that demonstrates out-of-the-box ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider with ASP.Net MVC: [ASP.NET MVC - Authenticate users against Active Directory, but require username and password to be inputted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147864/asp-net-mvc-authenticate-users-against-active-directory-but-require-username)