# Develop a Login-Page for a WebSite based on Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I'm working on a web project based on Windows Server 2008 R2, Asp.Net 4 & MVC3 in C# and Active Directory.

01- My new created Web Site should have a Login Page which will authorize a user against the Active Directory.

02 -The Login Page should also remember when a User previously logged-in and allow access without re-entering the password all the time / it should also work on mobile device (Phone Gap and Sencha).

03 - The web site would be hosted on a Server which has access to AD (Intranet) directly.

I'm very new at Active Directory, although I made several searches I still have some doubts and confusion and I would love have your clarifications:

- Does the .Net have Classes specifically designed to make easier connected and authorizing a User against AD? What is the easier way to go for web applications?
- Regarding point 02, how avoid a User re-entering the Password on subsequential log-in? Can I use AD and Cookies? Which Class are designed for this in .Net?
- Regarding point 03, do I need some special configuration on the AD to allow access from my website (running on a intranet where AD is accessible), I heard about LDAP.. does it make sense in my case?

Many thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Maybe this could help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147864/asp-net-mvc-authenticate-users-against-active-directory-but-require-username

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you start by looking at the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`.  There's lots of info on MSDN, including [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx), which describes how to use Forms Authentication with multiple domains (your case is simpler, you only have one domain).

The ASP.NET `Login` control has a "Remember Me" feature - you could look at how this works and create an MVC equivalent.