# Set user roles on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, roles

I need some help, I am making a role based menu. I'm using LDAP Active Directory to log In.

I can log in but I cannot get the roles from the groups of AD.

I try to use a role provider but cant get it to work. I get the groups using:

```
private ArrayList setRoles()
{
    ArrayList rolesList = new ArrayList();
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://**********");
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ds.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=test)"; // your username

    SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();

    foreach (string g in result.Properties["memberOf"])
        rolesList.Add(g);
    return rolesList;
}
```

Now, I need to "set" the roles somewhere in order to use

```
User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

and

```
[Authorize role...]
public bla bla bla()
```

Any ideas, links, etc?

PD: IM USING FORMS AUTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have experience working with AD, however, what you need to do is set the User property of HttpContext with a Principal that has the roles.

An approach I have previously created was to create a custom authorization attribute that inherits from AuthorizationAttribute.

```
public class AuthorizeActiveDirectoryAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;

        //Your code to get the list of roles for the current user

        var formsIdentity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
        filterContext.HttpContext.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(formsIdentity, rolesList.ToArray());

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

}
```

You would then apply it to your action methods

```
[AuthorizeActiveDirectory role...]
public bla bla bla()
```

This will also allow you to use `User.IsInRole("Admin")`

Comment: it works perfect but... if i only want to retrive the groups/roles 1 time (login function)??? then use them en the authorizeDA? pd: tks XD

Comment: Then in the login page, you would need to set a cookie with the roles and read the roles on each request. This is essentially how membership provider and roles provider works: You will need to recreate the HttpContext.User on _EACH_ request.

Comment: ok, I guess roles can be stored on session??? and check if they exist to retrieve on OnAuthorization()

Comment: Yes they can. Then on the OnAuthorization() you would get them and use that to create the GenericPrincipal.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to manually do this. Using the built in role provider should accomplish the task by setting it in the web.config.

[Active Directory Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx)

[Windows Token Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx)

**UPDATE:** Here's a question on StackOverflow that covers setting this up with an ActiveDirectory membership provider but still using Forms Authentication.

[ASP.NET MVC - Authenticate users against Active Directory, but require username and password to be inputted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147864/asp-net-mvc-authenticate-users-against-active-directory-but-require-username)

Comment: ups, I forgot to say I'm authenticating with forms, so win token Role P will not work?

Comment: You can still use the Active Directory Membership Provider and use Forms Authentication to actually obtain the user credentials. You just have to validate them in your controller action with `Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)` Here's a question on StackOverflow that covers this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147864/asp-net-mvc-authenticate-users-against-active-directory-but-require-username