# ASP.NET MVC - Authenticate users against Active Directory automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing a MVC application that will require a user to be authenticated against an AD. how to create log in page in MVC to create an Intranet Application that automatically authenticates a user against an AD

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Authenticate users against Active Directory, but require username and password to be inputted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147864/asp-net-mvc-authenticate-users-against-active-directory-but-require-username)

Comment: This is irritating: Login page, which automatically does a login?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Intranet Template provided by Microsoft Visual Studio, which does exactly what you want out of the box?

Your requirement is paradox. Why do you want a login page, which does login a user automatically, while being logged in by visiting the (main-)site automatically, does not require the visitor to do anything at all, because he is already authenticated by entering his credentials at the windows-logon

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built in windows authentication feature. the example is in [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs)

if you need mixed authenticated for example you want the user can access from outside using their AD it will involve either two applications or two different pages for authentication types. find the example [here](http://aspalliance.com/553_Mixed_Mode_Authentication.all)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if you actually want a login page that automatically authenticates a user that visits the main site. Maybe your wording is a bit confusing there.

I'll asumme you want your Web-App to be able to authenticate users against AD after having to log in with intranet credentials. If that's the case, you might want to have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa292114%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) detailing how to set that up using IIS and an ASP.NET app.

If not, please disregard this answer.