# user authentication withn OU using LDAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, ldap

I am trying to authenticate user using LDAP

I am using this code:

```
public bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd)
{

DirectoryEntry nRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.134.1.142/dc=testDomain,dc=com");
nRoot.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
nRoot.Username = "uid=username,dc=testDomain,DC=com";  //full dn
nRoot.Password = "pwd";

try
{ 
//Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
Object obj = nRoot.NativeObject;

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(nRoot);

search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
search.Filter = "uid=username";               
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid");

SearchResult sr = search.FindOne();
if(null == sr )
{
  return false;
}
// Update the new path to the user in the directory
_path = sr.Path;
_filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["uid"][0];
  }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
 }
 return true;
 }
```

Here if the user is not a part of any OU the code runs fine but if it is a part of an OU it won't work and ii get an error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   at
>    // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
>    Object obj = nRoot.NativeObject;

How do I get the user validated belonging to an OU or any other group??

I tried hard coding the OU to and it worked, but i cannot ask a user to enter his OU

```
 nRoot.Username = "uid=username,ou=test,dc=testDomain,DC=com";  //full dn
```

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-sharp-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory/499716#499716 - does that help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the username, find the object whose uid=username, and then read the distinguishedName attribute or else the name of the returned object (which will be the full DN) and log in with that discovered full DN.

Answer (score 1):

```
string ldapsrv = "mydomain.com:389";
string dc_oq = "OU=domain_app_auth,DC=domain,DC=uk,DC=com";//,
user_nme = "username";
pws = "password";

using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ldapsrv, dc_oq, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Negotiate))
{
    isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(user_nme, pws);
}
```