# Given user id, password, and a subdomain name, how can I obtain the top-level domain name for a user account?

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, ldap, domain-name

I'm writing a program (`WinForms`, `C#`) that runs on a `Win 7` client machine. It obtains credentials from the user (user id, password, and subdomain name) and uses them to authenticate (via `Active Directory`) to other servers to which the program remotely connects. The other servers are on a domain different than the domain the `Win 7` client machine is on.

Using the `NetworkCredential`, `LdapDirectoryIdentifier`, and `LdapConnection` classes, I can test the credentials with no more than the user id, password, and subdomain name (See answer for S.O. [Why does Active Directory validate last password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949501/why-does-active-directory-validate-last-password)).

For example, for the user account `ssmith@xyz.gov`, I need only provide `ssmith` (user id), the password for `ssmith`, and `xyz` (the `subdomain`). I don't need to provide the `top-level domain name` (`gov` in this case).

Now, I want to programmatically obtain the `top-level domain name` for this user account  (`gov` in this case). I've examined the properties and methods of the `NetworkCredential`, `LdapDirectoryIdentifier`, and `LdapConnection` classes. I've looked over the other classes in the [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't see a way to programmatically obtain the `top-level domain name`.

Given `user id`, `password`, and `subdomain` name, how can I obtain the `top-level domain name` for a user account?

Here is my code. Given a user account of ssmith@xyz.gov, My call looks like this (asterisks represent a SecureString password)

```
bool result = ValidateCredentials("ssmith","******", "xyz");
```

Here is my code for the method.

```
private const int ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE = 0x31;

private bool ValidateCredentials(string username, SecureString ssPassword, string domain)
{

    //suports secure string 
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, ssPassword, domain);

    LdapDirectoryIdentifier id = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(domain);

    using (LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(id, credentials, AuthType.Kerberos))
    {
        connection.SessionOptions.Sealing = true;
        connection.SessionOptions.Signing = true;

        try
        {
            // The only way to test credentials on a LDAP connection seems to be to attempt a 
            // Bind operation, which will throw an exception if the credentials are bad
            connection.Bind();
        }
        catch (LdapException lEx)
        {
            credentials = null;
            id = null;

            if (ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE == lEx.ErrorCode)
            {
                return false;
            }

            throw;
        }
    }

    credentials = null;
    id = null;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does your declaration of your `LdapDirectoryIdentifier` object look like if you don't already know the domain?

Comment: @GabrielLuci: I added code for the call to my method and the method. Please see above. The user will know the subdomain `xyz`, but perhaps not the top-level domain `gov`. And, `LdapDirectoryIdentifier` apparently doesn't require the top-level domain in this case

Comment: So doesn't the `domain` variable already contain the name of the top level domain?

Comment: No. Just subdomain name. Details are above in my question

Comment: I see. You're using the short name of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a successful bind, then the full DNS name of the domain will be in the `LdapConnection` object:

```
var domain = connection.SessionOptions.DomainName;
```

In this case, that would be "xyz.gov". If you need just "gov", then you can just take everything after the last dot:

```
var tld = domain.Substring(domain.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: "After a successful bind". Thanks - it did not occur to me to look at my `connection` object **after** the successful bind :-(

Comment: Searching only for the last dot will break horribly in cases such as a `.co.uk` domain name. Depending on the need, you may instead choose to split on the first dot.

Comment: I guess I could modify the signature of the method to pass the fully qualified domain name back out: `private bool ValidateCredentials(string username, SecureString ssPassword, string domain, out string fqdn)`. See this: "The `out` keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference.". [out parameter modifier (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

Comment: Or, if you're using the latest Visual Studio, you can use C# 7's new feature of [returning multiple values](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/): `private (bool, string) ValidateCredentials(...)` then `return (true, domainName);`