# Check user and password vs Active Directory in SQL

Tags: sql, active-directory

I would like to know if it is possible from sql directly to check a username and a password in Active directory. I mean without CLR functions.

I know is possible to get the list of users using Openrowset from a linked server and I was thinking if I can somehow put the password as a "where" parameter to that query and check the number of returned rows.

Thank you

Comment: I know how to do it directly in C#, I hoped there was also a SQL version... Can you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The user's password in Windows is **not** available in clear text anywhere, so you cannot just compare it in a `WHERE` clause....

See how to do it [very easily in C# in my answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-sharp-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory/499716#499716) - but you can't do it inside SQL Server