# Validating PowerShell PSCredential

Tags: security, powershell

Let's say I have a `PSCrendential` object in PowerShell that I created using `Get-Credential`.

How can I validate the input against Active Directory ?

By now I found this way, but I feel it's a bit ugly :

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")


function Validate-Credentials([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$credentials)
{
    $pctx = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, "domain")
    $nc = $credentials.GetNetworkCredential()
    return $pctx.ValidateCredentials($nc.UserName, $nc.Password)
}

$credentials = Get-Credential

Validate-Credentials $credentials
```

**[Edit, two years later]** For future readers, please note that `Test-Credential` or `Test-PSCredential` are better names, because `Validate` is not a valid powershell verb (see `Get-Verb`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` is the less ugly way:

This is using ADSI (more ugly?):

```
$cred = Get-Credential #Read credentials
$username = $cred.username
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password

# Get current domain using logged-on user's credentials
$CurrentDomain = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI]"").distinguishedName
$domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($CurrentDomain,$UserName,$Password)

if ($domain.name -eq $null)
{
 write-host "Authentication failed - please verify your username and password."
 exit #terminate the script.
}
else
{
 write-host "Successfully authenticated with domain $domain.name"
}
```

Comment: I understand that PSCredentials is authentication provider agnostic (it's basically a simple container for username /password), but this requirement sounds very common for me.

Comment: @SteveB It's a really common task for sysadmin and developper especially for those working in AD that's why (IMO) microsoft do AccountManagement. Here you can see a variety of way used in c# to do this task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-sharp-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory

Comment: In fact, general development best practices applies here. Especially I can hide the complexity in this function and then simply call the function :)

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue with an installer and required to verify the service account details supplied. I wanted to avoid using the AD module in Powershell as I wasn't 100% this would be installed on the machine running the script.

I did the test using the below, it is slightly dirty but it does work.

```
try{
    start-process -Credential $c -FilePath ping -WindowStyle Hidden
} catch {
    write-error $_.Exception.Message
    break
}
```

Comment: Neither my question nor @cb. answer requires having the AD module loaded. It actually relies on some .Net classes related to AD, which are always available in PowerShell.