# How can I verify PowerShell credentials are domain credentials?

Tags: powershell, authentication, active-directory, credentials

The solution posted here is what I am trying below: [Validating PowerShell PSCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802850/validating-powershell-pscredential)

My script requires domain credentials to be passed as arguments. Here is how I'm trying to validate the creds:

```
if ($username -and $pass) {
  $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
  $Credentials = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $Password

  $TestUsername = $Credentials.username
  $TestPassword = $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password

  # Get current domain using logged-on user's credentials
  $CurrentDomain = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI]"").distinguishedName
  $domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($CurrentDomain,$TestUsername,$TestPassword)

  if ($domain.name -eq $null) {
   write-host "Authentication failed - please verify your username and password."
   exit #terminate the script.
  } else {
   write-host "Successfully authenticated with domain $domain.name"
  }

}
```

But for some reason, this always leads me to `"Authentication failed - please verify your username and password"`. What is the problem, and would your solution also work from a *runas* command where creds are not passed in as arguments?

Comment: I would recommend against passing plain-text passwords as arguments to functions.

Comment: Do you have any input on how I could verify that the user in a runas command is a valid domain account? To be clear, I still need answers to both cases.

Comment: Because when run across multiple computers, the user account gets locked  out if the password is entered incorrectly and too many failed authentication attempts occur.

Comment: I will admit something seems off here as I can replicate your issue but you _could_ count failures in your process as well and set a threshold to prevent your issue as well.

Comment: If you fail on one computer, then I would recommend stopping the process and informing the user there was an error.