# How to login to Active Directory?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, active-directory, authorization, windows-server

I have a username and password for active directory and I want login to active directory using C#. How I can do this in Windows Forms?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Login - then what?

Comment: Call Some `WCF` services that has `WS-Http Binding`

Comment: So do you want to login into Active Directory or into Windows Server which is into a domain?

Comment: I want to login In Active Directory

Comment: You keep repeating that - elaborate! What is it you want to do? What do you want to _accomplish_?

Comment: Does it possible to login to AD using `NetworkCredential`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go. This method validates `username/password` against Active Directory, and has been a part of my toolbox of functions for quite some time.

```
//NOTE: This can be made static with no modifications
public bool ActiveDirectoryAuthenticate(string username, string password)
{
    bool result = false;
    using (DirectoryEntry _entry = new DirectoryEntry())
    {
        _entry.Username = username;
        _entry.Password = password;
        DirectorySearcher _searcher = new DirectorySearcher(_entry);
        _searcher.Filter = "(objectclass=user)";
        try
        {
            SearchResult _sr = _searcher.FindOne();
            string _name = _sr.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
            result = true;
        }
        catch
        { /* Error handling omitted to keep code short: remember to handle exceptions !*/ }
    }

    return result; //true = user authenticated!
}
```

The software executing this must be run on a computer inside the domain, obviously (or you would have no Active Directory to authenticate your credentials against).

Comment: What is difference between your solution and NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass", "Domain");? can you explain more please

Comment: NetworkCredential is just an object with some data inside, it doesn't validate anything.

Answer (score 6):

This Question is from a couple of years ago, I hope this answer can help people in the future.
This is working for me:

Add these references:

- using System.DirectoryServices;
- using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

After that, you can use this code in your app:

```
   PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOUR DOMAIN");
   bool Valid = pc.ValidateCredentials("User", "password");
```

The variable called: **Valid**, will show you a **True** value if the logIn is Ok.

For more information you can visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory). The page is from here, **stackOverFlow**, and it will show you a lot of information about: "login with MS Active Directory"

Answer (score 5):

## Solution

Connecting to an Active Directory is very easy.

You must use the `DirectoryEntry` object (in the namespace `System.DirectoryServices`).

The constructor for this object takes three strings in parameters:

- the path to the Active Directory. This path has the format: `LDAP://your-name-AD`
- the username for the connection
- the corresponding password

## Example

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

try
{
   DirectoryEntry Ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://your-name-AD", "Login", "Password");
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: what is `DirectoryEntry`? I want to user `using System.Security.Principal;` thanks

Comment: What is difference between your solution and `NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass", "Domain");`? can you explain more please

Comment: [`DirectoryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=vs.80).aspx) handles all actions performed on an AD ; not [`NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

a shorter answer is to add the **reference** **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement**

Then use 
**UserPrincipal.Current.Context.ValidateCredentials("username", "password");**

But i guess you will need to be joined to the domain you want to validate for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I encountered an DirectoryOperationException with the code above, and I solved it by adding the third parameter "ContextOptions.Negotiate".