# Authenticate credentials remote server

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

I'm trying to check if the username/password for a remote computer, entered by a user on a WPF form are correct.

I have those strings: username, password and ip address.

I saw something about about "DirectoryEntry" but couldn't get it to work  - the user is always authenticated even when the password is incorrect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about Active Directory authentication ? Because yes, there is a way to check whether a combination of username/password is is correct.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about Active Directory authentication. Could you please show me how?

Comment: See if this answer helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory

Comment: Should I use my IP as the domain? I use this: `        private bool Authenticate(string username, string password, string domain) 
        {
            PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
            return (pc.ValidateCredentials(username, ServerPassword, ContextOptions.Negotiate));
        }` but I get PrincipalServerDownException...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, but the way I've done it before is like this (using DirectoryEntry), it goes like this:

```
string ldapConnectionString = @"LDAP://[domain_server]/CN=Users,DC=[domain]"

using (var de = new DirectoryEntry(
    ldapConnectionString, "username", "password", 
    AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
{
    return de.NativeObject != null; // if not null -> user is valid
}
```

Edit: What this code will do is, validate a combination of a username/password against active directory. I think I misunderstood you (if what you mean is, to see if a user CAN connect to a particular server -> as in HAS PERMISSION to, I'm not quite sure how to do that, or even if it's possible).

Comment: I get server is not operational exception. Am I writing the ldap string correctly: `string ldapConnectionString = @"LDAP://10.0.0.160/CN=Users,DC=[10.0.0.160]";`?

Comment: I believe it should be something like this -> @"LDAP://10.0.0.160/CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN_NAME";

Comment: Let's say you had the domain "COMPANY.US", you would go like this -> @"LDAP://10.0.0.160/CN=Users,DC=COMPANY, DC=US";

Comment: Is 10.0.0.160 your domain controller or is it the server you're trying to connect ? (it should be the domain controller)

Comment: it's the server I'm trying to connect to. but then how do I know what's the domain controller, and how do choose this specific computer in the domain, out of all other computers?