# Login Authentication using Active Directory in the Intranet...Possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating this project to be deployed in our company's intranet. I am using this code to authenticate the users login:

```
entry.Username = strUserName;
entry.Password = strPassword;

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
searcher.Filter = "(objectclass=user)";
try
{
    searcher.FindOne();
    return true;
}
```

It working well on my localhost, but when I deployed it the intranet, I can't log in.

Now my question is, can I access the Directory over the intranet? or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Check this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory

Comment: Side note: Consider using normal Windows authentication if possible instead of manually dealing with passwords. Handling plain text passwords securely is hard and if your company would have security code reviewers plain text passwords may make deployment of your code much harder.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov However, the passwords are being dealt on the server side. Also using secure transport layer augments security. I don't think Windows Authentication is feasible when you want to port from Intranet over to the Internet. Plus other alternatives are also available like Windows Forms Authentication.

Comment: @Daniel Nachtrub: What should i put in the LDAP path? im sorry im just a newbie at this..

Comment: Just the Name of your active Directory Domain (e.g. "mydomain.local")

Comment: Its WORKING! :) atleast in my local..but when it comes to the intranet it throws this error "The authentication mechanism is unknown"....

Answer (score 1):

A simpler method would be to use `System.DirectoryServices` and  `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Use this in a function returning Boolean:

```
Dim context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName)
If context.ValidateCredentials(userAlias, userPassword, ContextOptions.Negotiate) Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
```

The snippet is in VB, but you get the idea. Replace *domainName* with your domain name, *userAlias* with your username, and *userPassword* with your password.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @abhitalnks :) but sad to say im using an older version of VS it doesn't recognize the .AccountManagement

Comment: Yes, .NetFx 3.5 required. You will have to add a reference before `using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

Comment: @CodeMeCodeYou As an afterthought: (1) Are you sure you are using `entry.AuthenticationType = DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure` in your code before specifying username/password? (2) Did you try prepending the domain name before the username, like thor\username ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me in the past:

```
var ldapConnectionString = "LDAP://servername/CN=Users,DC=domainname,DC=com";

using (var de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapConnectionString, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
{
    if(de.NativeObject != null)
    {
        // user is valid ...
    }
}
```

You need a reference to: `System.DirectoryServices`

Comment: Thanks @Dimitar Dimitrov, one question, what is the "ldapConnectionString" ? thanks

Comment: @CodeMeCodeYou It's the connection string to your domain basically. I've done a small edit to give you an idea how it looks like

Comment: How can i know the path i should use? im sorry im new at this.. My domian is THOR..

Comment: Is it just THOR or you have something like THOR.XX ?

Comment: @CodeMeCodeYou Anyway it would be something like `LDAP://[DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_IP]/CN=Users,DC=THOR,DC=XX`

Comment: i got the code working and it works well in my localhost..but it throws an error when i publish it the intranet, Here;s the error : "The authentication mechanism is unknown"