# How to ask the approver to input his password before approving a document in SharePoint Doc Lib

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

We have a scenario where we want the user to enter his AD password before approving a document in the document library. The flow goes this way

- Approver receives an email, with the task information
- He views the document, and then selects "Approve/Reject", and Approves the document.
- He should now be prompted for his AD credentials, and only if these credentials are verified, the document should be marked as Approved.

I am not sure how to go about asking the password to the Approver, and getting it verified in the AD?

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I cannot ask the user to mention his AD Path. That's out of question. Since this code is going to be deployed on multiple client servers, I cant go about asking everybody to put in their AD path in some config file.

Comment: I am able to do everything I mentioned above, from email, approving the document etc. All I need to know now is, how do I validate his credentials? There has to be something in directory services where I can pass the users username and password and it would return me true or false?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory