# Log AD users in

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I have a login form written in C# and I want only AD users to be able to login.
How should I do this?

```
string UserName = "";
string Pass = "";
```

Comment: May you show some code ? We would be able to understand what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that this is not a best practice, but, depending on your security needs, you could allow all domain users and exclude local users by checking just the `UserDomainName` in the `Form_Load`. This simple approach piggybacks on their computer login, and does not have the complexity of any LDAP/AD calls.

```
if (SystemInformation.UserDomainName.ToString() == "myDomain")
{
    // your normal form load code here
}
else
{
   form1.Close(); //this is a simple but effective to pull the rug out from 
                  //under them if they do not have the permissions
   //TODO email the application administrator the `SystemInformation.UserName` of the user who was not given permissions
}
```

In my environment, since our in-house apps are deployed via `ClickOnce` (installed per user per computer), a similar approach (we compare usernames too) has always been sufficient for us.

Comment: This is not what I meant. I want to authorize domain user name and PASSWORD!! from the AD

Comment: You did not say in your question that you wanted to authenticate users. You said that you wanted a winForm that only domain users could use. This will do that, IF your users are logged into a windows machine using their AD credentials. It piggybacks on the current windows user.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not an ASP.Net app the active directory membership provider will work just fine.

Here is info on how to use this library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx

and here is some more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to verify credentials to Active Directory in order to allow AD users in you application, you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23059698/922977).

You'll find how to verify the content of your textboxes and verify if username and passowrd matches (directly with the AD).