# Bypass Login Screen With Domain Credentials C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Hi i am looking to implement Active Directory Single Sign On in my Application.

If user has Signed in the Domain, he should not be able to see the Login Screen, The Domain User will have to log into the Domain to Access the application.

Please Suggest how should i implement that and what are best practices.
Any links for ref are welcome

Thanks

Comment: What type of application is this? A Winforms/WPF thick client app? An ASP.Net website of some kind? Something else?

Comment: Its a Web Application, Using WCF and Entity Framework.. No Custom asp.net in it.

Comment: Can you show some code to help us to help you ? How far are you in the implementation ? You should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23059698/922977. It's about WinForm, but the logic is there. Juste need some redirection to a login page if not and AD user.