# .NET Active Directory PrincipalContext setup

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap

I'm having difficulty setting up my authentication with active directory.

I have a LDAP server at `ldap://server-1` and the domain is `"DC=company,DC=com"`

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory), I tried to setup the scheme like:

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ldap://server-1", "DC=company,DC=com"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

But I keep getting error `The server could not be contacted / The LDAP server is unavailable`. I've tried lots of variations of using the server name and the domain but I don't know much about the LDAP protocol, so don't know if I'm setting things up right.

I *know* the LDAP is available because I get results from cmd line `dsquery DC=company,DC=com` - type queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this - use the server name and the `dc=` strings as your server name - and leave the "starting point" out (and also: make sure to use **ALL UPPERCASE** on your `LDAP://` prefix - that's ***crucial***!):

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://server-1/dc=company,dc=com"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

Does that work?

**Update:** read my own answer to that question you linked to again, you need to supply this: a **domain name** (just a string; can be `NULL` to indicate the "default" domain) to the second parameter, and optionally a **container DN** to the third parameter - so try this:

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "dc=company,dc=com"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```