# How can I authenticate to a domain?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I've got a windows server which runs our team foundation server and my self written .NET-Webservice.
The windows server acts inside of a domain. My webserver gets now the username and password for other computers inside of the domain. How can I authenticate them on my webservice? I want that only users, which are part of the domain, are able to work with the webservice.

Comment: What web service - IIS hosted, self hosted ? Googling for "windows authentication" might help you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the username and password as parameter to the API you can use the method described here:

[Validate a username and password against Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory)

If it is a IIS hosted Application you can configured it in the web.config (windows authentication)

Comment: I have my application hosted on the IIS, but I cant use a username and password for a windows-authentification. So the windows-authentification checks automatically if a computer is already inside of the domain, or not. Did I get this right?

Comment: Yes, if it is hostet in IIS you can add <authentication mode="Windows" /> to the <system.web> Section in the web.config