# Validate user credentials against windows login

Tags: c#, .net

I've read a couple of posts on SO regarding user authentication on Windows and it seems that one is able to retrieve the username, but not the password of the logged-in user, as it is hashed in one direction.

My question is: Is it possible to validate the username/password provided in the Windows Form app as a Windows login?

Essentially, my goal is to ask the user to provide once again his Windows password (username would be prompted automatically), and to check somehow if those credentials would pass as a Windows login. If so, how?

I know I can retrive the username like so: `Environment.UserName;` But beyond that I'm lost.

Comment: you want combine forms authentication with windows authentication?

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa yes.

Comment: checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory

Comment: they use active directory

Comment: I'm guessing there is no .NET api for this and you'll have to pInvoke of these https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177(v=vs.85).aspx Good luck with that.