# Authenticate user from specific groups on LDAP server using C#

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, ldap, nested-groups

I have a few nested groups on LDAP server and users in these groups. 
How can I authenticate users with given username and password by searching only in groups(not whole domain)? Does bind do this?

Comment: What kind of LDAP server do you have? You can restrict the scope of searching by providing a Bind OU, but I'm not sure what LDAP service are you using.

Comment: I don't know, I have only list od domains and groups such as domainName.com dc=first, dc = second, ou = third... And users and passwords are stored in that ou group, but of course, I can't see them. I need just to check are they in that groups and does password is correct. Can I do this with just bind method?

Comment: Actually, I asked for the type of LDAP Server. Can you confirm if it is a Microsoft based Windows Active Directory server?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have access using either Novell.Directory.Ldap or System.DirectoryServices.Protocols LdapConnection classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by you in the comment section of this question, the LDAP server you're talking about is an Active Directory server. So, my answer is based on [this famous answer about how to validate a username and password against Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499716/3482140), except that I've made a modification based on your requirement to limit the scope of search.

If you work on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace's [PrincipalContext Constructor (ContextType, String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348316(v=vs.110).aspx) and easily verify your credentials:

```
// create a "principal context"
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOUR.DOMAIN",
             "OU=Where,OU=You,OU=Wanna,OU=Search,DC=YOUR,DC=DOMAIN"))
   // change your container to a base OU where all your users are located.
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```