# PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials gives false for even correct credentials randomly

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, principalcontext

I've implemented login through Active Directory credentials in my web application. It first authenticates the user by `ValidateCredentials(userName, password)` and then verifies if it exists in certain groups. The unit tests are failing randomly for the same user. I've got a test fixture that contains 22 tests with both correct and wrong values.

I've already tried passing `ContextOptions` and username and password for creating `PrincipalContext`. I've tried retries after 1 second on fail but no result. I've tried using `HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()`;

**Method for authentication through AD**

```
public static bool AuthenticateViaAd(string userName, string password)
{
    using(var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "AD.DomainName"))
    {
        return ctx.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
    }
}
```

**Method for verifying UserGroups**

```
public static List<UserRole> GetUserRolesForAdUser(string userName, string password)
{
    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "AD.DomainName", userName, password))
    {
        // find a user
        var userId = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);
        if (userId == null)
            return NoRoles;

        // find the group in question
        var groupDataProcessor = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Consts.AdGroupDataProcessors) ??
                                 throw new InvalidOperationException("Data Processor group is not present. Please contact IT.");
        var groupSupport = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Consts.AdGroupSupport) ??
                           throw new InvalidOperationException("Support group is not present. Please contact IT.");
        var groupSales = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Consts.AdGroupSales) ??
                         throw new InvalidOperationException("Sales group is not present. Please contact IT.");

        // check if user is member of that group
        if (userId.IsMemberOf(groupDataProcessor))
            return DataProcessorsRoles;
        if (userId.IsMemberOf(groupSupport))
            return SupportRoles;
        if (userId.IsMemberOf(groupSales))
            return SalesRoles;
        return NoRoles;
    }
}
```

**Error message in GetUserRolesForAdUser**

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException : The user name or password is incorrect.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)
```

Comment: Have you tried just not using the `useName` and `password` in `GetUserRolesForAdUser`? If the computer you run this from is joined to the same domain you are connecting to (or a trusted domain) then you don't need it.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes, I did try that. When I run the tests 2 or 3 times continuously it again returns false for ValidateCredentials randomly.

Comment: That's an odd one. Do you see any errors in the Event Viewer when it fails?

Comment: You could also use `LdapConnection` to validate the credentials, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033489/1202807). See if it gives you different results.