# DirectoryEntry increase bad password count by 2

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I'm trying to validate an AD user using the following code:

```
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domainTxt.Text}", usernameTxt.Text, passwordTxt.Text))
{
    var nO = de.NativeObject; //verify credentials
}
```

When calling `de.NativeObject` and the password is incorrect the bad password attempt count increases by 2 instead of 1.

Using this powershell script to check the count:

```
C:\Users\administrator> Get-ADUser -Filter {userprincipalname -eq "x@y.z"} -Properties badPwdCount
```

I found out that the reason for this is that `DirectoryEntry` uses `AuthenticationTypes.Secure` by default, which is fair enough, that's what I need actually, if I change it to anything else, the bad password count increases by one as expected.

Does anyone know how can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure why, but the documentation for [AuthenticationTypes.Secure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes) says:

> Active Directory Domain Services uses Kerberos, and possibly NTLM, to authenticate the client.

That *could* mean that when one method fails for whatever reason, it tries again with the other. You might be able to see this by monitoring network traffic with something like Wireshark.

A way to work around this might be to use `LdapConnection` to validate the credentials (if that's all you need the connection to LDAP for). There's a good example of that in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033489/1202807). It has the added benefit of telling you why the validation failed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately my problem with this solution is, that as far as I can tell LdapConnection is not secure unless I use SSL, which I could also do with DirectoryEntry (and it wouldn't increase the bad password count by 2). Using SSL certificate might not be viable for me in all cases.

Comment: You can specify the [`AuthType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.authtype?view=netframework-4.8) with `LdapConnection`, just like you can with `DirectoryEntry`, but with the added benefit that you can choose Kerberos *or* NTLM specifically (both of which do not send plain-text passwords), without having it automatically failover to the other if you don't want it to.

Comment: Unfortunatelly if I use AutType.Negotiate I have the same issue, so it seems like having to set it to Kerberos will have to do. Thanks.