# How to authenticate in LDAP in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

I am new to LDAP related coding and today I am asked to develop a code to check the users authentication against LDAP.

The tutorials I have found online are so simple but our company's Directory is so complicated that I don't know how to write a code for that. Here is the info of the LDAP . I have changed the company name to hide the name.

```
string domain = "ou=People,dc=my,dc=com";
string LDAP_Path= "dc01.my.com;
string LDAPconnect= "LDAP://dc01.my.com/";
```

Here is a code I have developed but it gives me error when run "   LdapResult = LdapSearcher.FindOne();":

```
    string domain = "ou=People,dc=my,dc=com";
    string password = "";
    string userName = "";

    // define your connection
    LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(LDAP_Path);

    try
    {
        // authenticate the username and password
        using (ldapConnection)
        {
            // pass in the network creds, and the domain.
            var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

            // if we're using unsecured port 389, set to false. If using port 636, set this to true.
            ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;

            // since this is an internal application, just accept the certificate either way
            ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

            // to force NTLM\Kerberos use AuthType.Negotiate, for non-TLS and unsecured, just use AuthType.Basic
            ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

            // authenticate the user
            ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
            Response.Write( "connect ldap success");
        }
    }
    catch (LdapException ldapException)
    {
        Response.Write(ldapException + " <p>Ad connect failed</p>");
        //Authentication failed, exception will dictate why
    }
    string strTmp0 = LDAPconnect + domain;
    string user = "memberId";
    string pwd = "memberPwd";
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry LdapEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(strTmp0, "cn=" + user, pwd, AuthenticationTypes.None);
    DirectorySearcher LdapSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(LdapEntry);
    LdapSearcher.Filter = "(cn=" + user + ")";
    string value = string.Empty;
    SearchResult LdapResult=null;
    try
    {
         LdapResult = LdapSearcher.FindOne();
     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
 // .............get Error msg : username an password  uncorrect

    }
    if ((LdapResult != null))
    {
        Response.Write("ldapresult not null");
    }
```

Could anybody help plz?

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: it gives me error msg "username an password  uncorrect"  when run " LdapResult = LdapSearcher.FindOne();":

Comment: string LDAPconnect= "LDAP://dc01.my.com"/"; is it correct i mean escape character?

Comment: @Always_a_learner I have modified it to  "string LDAPconnect= "LDAP://dc01.my.com/"; " , still get the same error

Comment: let me share you a fresh approach to validate user with email..i hope it will work validating user by email?

Comment: @Always_a_learner "LDAP://dc01.my.com" that looks like only the server name. Chekc [How can I figure out my ldap connection string](https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string). A connection string similar to `LDAP://ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org` works for me (no need to add the domain controller to the connection string because machine is already in the domain)

Comment: @Always_a_learner That sample only checks the email exists in the LDAP, it does not authenticate.

Comment: Is that the only information the exception gives you? `LdapConnection` should give you more info, which should tell you why the credentials were rejected. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033489/1202807) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In ldap connection setting , OP should use own configuration.

```
        // Ldap connection setting. this should setup according to organization ldap configuration 
        int portnumber = 12345;
        LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ldap.testxxxx.com", portnumber));
        ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous;
        ldapConnection.Bind();

        SearchRequest Srchrequest = null;
        SearchResponse SrchResponse = null;
        SearchResultEntryCollection SearchCollection = null;

        Hashtable UserDetails = new Hashtable();
        
        Srchrequest = new SearchRequest("distniguishged name e.g. o=testxxx.com", string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "preferredmail=test@testxxxx.com"), System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);
        SrchResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(Srchrequest);
        SearchCollection = SrchResponse.Entries;

        foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in SearchCollection)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry att in entry.Attributes)
            {
                if (((DirectoryAttribute)(att.Value)).Count > 0)
                {
                    UserDetails.Add(att.Key.ToString(), ((DirectoryAttribute)(att.Value))[0].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    UserDetails.Add(att.Key.ToString(), string.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        if (UserDetails.Count > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User does not exist");
        }
```

Comment: OP is trying to check user credentials connecting to the LDAP, your code does an anonymous LDAP query. Your code is useful in some scenarios, but probably is not what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DirectoryInfo conrstructor that has user and password arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_). That way, you don't need to do a query to the LDAP, you can simplify your code.

```cs
string username = "frederic";
string password = "myFanciPassword99";

string domain = "ou=People,dc=my,dc=com";
string LDAPconnect= "LDAP://dc01.my.com/";

string connectionString = LDAPconnect + domain;

bool userValid = false;

// Note: DirectoryEntry(domain, username, password) would also work
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionString, username, password);
try
{
    // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
    Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
    userValid = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```