# How to authenticate active directory admin user in c#?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I m developing simple c# based active directory application for testing for client requirement.
My client has active directory with admin credentials. Now I want to first authenticate active directory administrator if that is true then I want to check username and password from same active directory. Can anyone help me how to proceed for above requirements.
Thanks and regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this C# lib - Novell.Directory.Ldap

example code (use Admin account to authenticate)

```
 LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();
                conn.Connect(ldapHost, ldapPort);
                conn.Bind(loginAdmin, passwordAdmin);
```

Then you can manage users in the domain
e.g. delete operation

```
conn.Delete();
```

Comment: Thanks kordek21 for ur response. But I m working on active dirctory. Now I m bit confused how can I use LDAP connection to authenticate AD admin and password.